# mod_rewrite with question marks and ampersands (with PHP)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a PHP-based web app that I'm trying to apply Apache's mod_rewrite to.

Original URLs are of the form:
  http://example.com/index.php?page=home&x=5

And I'd like to transform these into:
  http://example.com/home?x=5

Note that while rewriting the page name, I'm also effectively "moving" the question mark.  When I try to do this, Apache happily performs this translation:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)\?(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&$2  [NC,L]
```

But it messes up the `$_GET` variables in PHP.  For example, a call to `http://example.com/home?x=88` yields only one `$_GET` variable (`page => home`).  Where did `x => 88` go?  However, when I change my rule to use an ampersand rather than a question mark:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)&(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&$2  [NC,L]
```

a call like `http://example.com/home&x=88` will work just as I'd expect it to (i.e. both the `page` and `x` $_GET variables are set appropriately).

The difference is minimal I know, but I'd like my URL variables to "start" with a question mark, if it's possible.  I'm sure this reflects my own misunderstanding of how mod_rewrite redirects interact with PHP, but  it seems like I should be able to do this (one way or another).

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
-Chris

Comment: The query string should always start with a question mark, not with an ampersand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)(?:$|\?(?:.+)) /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA,NE]
```

B escapes the backreference (shouldn't be necessary since it is matching [a-z]+, but in case you want to extend it later, it might be useful).

EDIT: added RewriteCond.
EDIT 2: QSA takes care of adding the ampersand.

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm - but can you explain why?  I'm no novice to PCRE (your regex is perfectly intelligible), but the semantics of how this is producing the desired result leaves me confused.

Comment: I suppose, specifically, why is the RewriteCond necessary?  Also, how does the QSA help if the subpatterns aren't being captured?

Comment: Th important flag is QSA (query string append); it appends the query string (the part after ?) of the original request to the rewritten request. It also takes take of adding either & or ? depending on whether the rewritten url already has a query string or not. NE is not really necessary here but it prevents escaping the rewritten URL. It would be useful if you add
/index.php?page=$1,$2; NE prevents the comma from becoming %2C

Comment: The RewriteCond is not really necessary. However, if you remove the L flag or impose an HTTP forward and allow the captured group to contain dots, you could find yourself in an infinite loop. So feel free to remove it.