# htaccess rewrite rule with escaped ampersand in $_GET fails

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, escaping, url-rewriting

I am encountering a problem with a get parameter in conjunction with a htaccess rewrite rule. 
Below is the urlencode()'ed link; the rewrite rule I use to redirect to index.php, and lastly, a print_r($_GET) on the index.php.
As you can see, the urlescaped ampersand is not part of the value for variable static, but instead and contrary to my expectation gets interpreted as a variable seperator. **Why?**

Initial link:

```
<a href="static/Game-Tech-%26-Arts-Lab">link</a>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /index.php?static=$1 [L]
```

index.php:

```
Array ( [static] => Game-Tech- [-Arts-Lab] => )
```

Comment: How did the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` look for that request? And does the rewriting not occur when you invoke the `index.php?static=...` manually?

Comment: Manually browsing to "index.php?static=Game-Tech-%26-Arts-Lab" shows the page just fine - the $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] reads "[QUERY_STRING] => static=Game-Tech-&-Arts-Lab"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ah, okay. Interesting. It seems there is a special solution for keeping that ampersand specifically escaped. Use the [`[B]` flag for Rewriterules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).

```
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /index.php?static=$1 [L,B]
```

This is supposed to urlencode special characters when interpolating the `$1` placeholder. It only works with Apache 2.2 however I believe.

Found a few references:

- http://www.dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/
- [mod_rewrite with question marks and ampersands (with PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842294/mod-rewrite-with-question-marks-and-ampersands-with-php)
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Ampersand_solution

Comment: Oh, that's news! That just fixed it. I will have to learn those rewrite flags some more - thank you for the help mario!

Comment: Didn't know about that one either. It's new.