# %26 in query string is breaking the $_GET part

Tags: php, query-string

for this page

```
www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Bell+%26+Gossett+101238+1.25"+Sweat+ChecktroLFlangeset/46
```

I am not getting value in `$_GET['s']`

the value in `$_GET['s']` should be `Bell Gossett 101238 1.25" Sweat ChecktroLFlangeset` but only `Bell` is passed into `$_GET['s']`

I already tried `urldecode()`, `htmlentities` but not of use.

My .httaccess file is like

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]
```

Comment: You shouldn't be getting anything in `$_GET`,  you have no `?` to start the query string with

Comment: broken mod_rewrite? Your rewrite doesn't seem to like `%`: try changing the `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` blocks to `[a-zA-Z0-9%_-]`

Comment: these are mod_rewrite 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]

Comment: You can change your regex to search till it finds a slash, like you do with the first row. This way, it won't break your checks. Something like... `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

As Second Rikudo wrote, your rewrite rules are not accepting the `&` character (%26).

Try this;

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]
```

Also, these rewriterules are not really efficient. I would go with something like this;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

And then do all the matching in PHP. There are a lot of frameworks that have excellent routing built in, you can use that or build your own, using something like the `explode()` function in PHP.

Comment: Getting internal server error using your rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\&]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]

Comment: Yes, because the '-' not is the last char in list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is than & (amperstand) char is a special char to apache (it separe parameters). So to identify this, use the [B] flag (In your case, append it after [L]:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L,B]
```

The write rules works, is second group than matches "s" parameter: /([^/]+)/, it can replace by /.+/. Works well to, I tested.

Based on: [htaccess rewrite rule with escaped ampersand in $_GET fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467254/htaccess-rewrite-rule-with-escaped-ampersand-in-get-fails)

Comment: I tried your rules with B flag but still it is giving wrong result
check here http://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Bell+%26+Gossett+101238+1.25%22+Sweat+ChecktroLFlangeset/46

Comment: Post your .htaccess. And they have a "RewriteEngine On" in first line?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L,B]

Comment: I tried without RewriteEngine On but still same thing

Comment: No, RewriteEngine On have to present in .htaccess. Test without RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I corrected this issue before encoding the url using
$keyword = str_replace("&","%26",$keyword);
$keyword = urlencode(str_replace("/","%2F",$keyword));

it works for me

Comment: So your problem is solved? You replace the '&' for other char and on decode your replace per '&' again, is this?

Comment: Yes, something like this as I replaced & with %26 and on encoding it becomes %2526

and I got url like this http://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Bell+%2526+Gossett+2NFI+Iron+Booster+Pump/46

My httaccess decodes this as I want

Comment: Cool, the problem is because '&' is a special char for apache. I tested with [B] flag and work but if for you not work, this workarround resolve the problem.