# Having issue with .htacces file and get method in php

Tags: php

I have URL with company.php?name=Son's.&.clothes

when I use `.htaccess` file it should be like
company/Son's.&.clothes

```
$url = $pro->vendor_company; ///
$url = str_replace('&', '%26', $url);// Here i replaced & with %26

http://localhost/worldsindia/name/Jai%20Industries%20Ltd. // Then it looks like that
```

And the output is

I use GET method in PHP to get the name from URL:

```
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
        $name = $_GET['name'];    

    }

    var_dump($name);
   Jai Industries Ltd.php
```

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $0.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s&()+/.']+)  company.php?name=$1 [NE,B,L]
```

The output of $name is like `Son's`

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite rule with escaped ampersand in $\_GET fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467254/htaccess-rewrite-rule-with-escaped-ampersand-in-get-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url requested isn't urlencoded.

The & character means new parameter in the get request.

```
url [questionmark] parametername [equals sign] value [ampersand] parametername [equals sign] value

url?foo=bar&baz=bal
```

will turn into:

```
$_GET = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'bal'
];
```

So the same logic applied to your url `company.php?name=Son's.&.clothes`, then in your case you get

```
$_GET = [
    'name' => 'Son\'s.',
    '.clothes' => null,
];
```

or if your webserver/php settings are different, the empty get variable might get dropped alltogether.

[urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your urls before rendering them with php, or javascript with [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or by manually encoding/replacing the ampersand with `%26`

```
company.php?name=Son's.%26.clothes
```

**On basis of the edited question**

```
$url = str_replace('&', '%26', $url);// Here i replaced & with %26
$url = urlencode($url);
```

Drop the first line. The urlencode will take care of that. Now you're urlencoding the escape sign of the %26.
Those two lines should be turned into:

```
 $url = urlencode($url);
```

Which will give

```
 http://localhost/worldsindia/name/Durgesh+Jaiswal+%26+Co
```

Now your rewrite rule is nonsensical

```
 RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()+/']+)  company.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

This checks if an url starts with the word company.
Your url starts with worldsinda
Even if it matches with that by swapping out company for worldsindia then your url would be turned into:

```
 company.php?name=name/Durgesh Jaiswal & Co
```

which is a weird get request to get. But then because it's a rewrite rule and not a redirect rule, it gets fed into the .htaccessfile from the top again.

So what you now have is the url:

```
 company.php?name=name/Durgesh Jaiswal & Co
```

Which will interpret the & as a parameter seperator, which will drop the second parameter because it's empty. So you end up with

```
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(21) "name/Durgesh Jaiswal "
}
```

Now to fix it, you need to fix your rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()+']+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()+']+)  company.php?company=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Here we set the base url `/company` so anything after company will be fed to the company.php file. Anything that's not a company will be fed to something else.

Now the parameters int he get request are

```
array(2) {
  ["company"]=>
  string(11) "worldsindia"
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "Durgesh Jaiswal "
}
```

We still don't have the part after the ampersand, this is because Apache does stuff, but mostly, because you don't have the ampersand in your redirect rule.

```
RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()&+']+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()+&']+)  test.php?company=$1&name=$2 [NE,L]
```

Now we end up with:

```
array(3) {
  ["company"]=>
  string(13) "worldwideinda"
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "Durgesh Jaiswal "
  ["Co"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

We can fix this by adding the B modifyier to the rewrite rule, read for more information https://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/development/using-and-path-apache-modrewrite-and-php/

```
 RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()&+']+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()+&']+)  test.php?company=$1&name=$2 [NE,B,L]
```

Which will result in

```
array(2) {
  ["company"]=>
  string(13) "worldwideinda"
  ["name"]=>
  string(20) "Durgesh+Jaiswal+&+Co"
}
```

Which is not nice to see because of the plusses. Better to let the url encoding replace them with the proper escape code, %20. You can do this with [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)
[image: working sample]

Comment: ok i used urlencode() and the url comes like this Durgesh+Jaiswal+%26amp%3B+Co but get['name'] is Durgesh Jaiswal only and how to replace %26amp

Comment: @ShadowShoot You're sending `"Durgesh+Jaiswal+&amp;+Co"` There's an html entity in there, that might be blocked for some reason by an overly zealous firewall. Can you try `"Durgesh+Jaiswal+%26+Co"`

Comment: @ShadowShoot You don't need to, your webserver will translate it to the correct character. And your sent parameter works perfectly as far as I can see https://imgur.com/6AvLwtI

Comment: but i get only Durgesh Jaiswal not remaining

Comment: What is the entire request you are doing? Are you doing the company.php request or are you doing a /company/whatevever request? Can you paste the url you are using?

Comment: @ShadowShoot added the answer.

Comment: ok i used it but when i used dot(.) in rewrite rule it comes Durgesh Jaiswal & Co.php  how this possible

Comment: can u check this because i have company name like Jai industries Ltd.(dot) after Ltd in url but come like Jai industries Ltd.php why

Comment: @ShadowShoot Can you please post the full url you're using? and show the rewrite rule you put in your .htaccess? Did you use the one I gave you? do your urls start with localhost/company/companyname?

Comment: @ShadowShoot You haven't made the rewrite url like I told you, there is no catching anything for company. Also a `.` isn't included in your regex filter `RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-\s\.()&\+']+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s()\.\+&']+)  test.php?company=$1&name=$2 [NE,B,L] `  also make sure your company parameters don't end with a . so Ltd. the dot will bestripped by the webserver/browser, for whatever reason. there needs to be a non space character behind it for it to be included. Also, don't use str_replace but use urlencode.

Comment: ok used as mention but for company name like  Innovation it comes like Innovation.php

Comment: @ShadowShoot You're not using the rewrite rule I gave you, I don't know what you're expecting of me.

Comment: this is my url localhost/worldsindia/company.php?name=Innovation worldindis is folder ok

Comment: ok can i use my rewrite rule of remove .php extension from url RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $0.php [NC,L]

Comment: @ShadowShoot I have no idea where you get the plusses from, but just pass the company name or whatever name to [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) example on https://ideone.com/ycRUl1

Comment: ok i understand but if i use this rewrite rule RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $0.php [NC,L] and your rewrite rule it comes Innovation like innovation .php

Comment: @ShadowShoot please take a look at the last image, the url that is in there. Does it resemble the url format you are using? if not, you're not doing it right. Read the *entire* answer from start to end, and try to understand each step and the logic behind it.

Comment: worldindia is folder in which company.php is file and you are using worldindia as a file?