# Laravel: Setup .htaccess of Folder outside of Laravel App

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I have Laravel installed in `/var/www/html`

I have a PHP script installed in `/var/www/html/i/`

The htaccess of `/var/www/html/` is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The htaccess of `/var/www/html/i/` is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?variable=$1

</IfModule>
```

Trouble is whenever I go to

`/i/somevariable`

I get a 404 error from my laravel app.

Comment: What webserver? You'll need to use a rewrite rule, and they're different for every webserver.

Comment: apache, I've got mod_rewrite turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a .htaccess file in your root folder with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/i/?$    index.php/i/?s=$1    [NC,L]
```

This should work fine.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/i/?$    index.php/i/?s=$1    [NC,L] 

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using apache 
read mod_rewrite
 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

dont just turn on,
use rewrite rule

Comment: ok I modified my question heavily, based on my htaccess file.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/using-mod-rewrite-to-rewrite-urls-with-question-marks-in-them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842294/mod-rewrite-with-question-marks-and-ampersands-with-php